# Trying to install oracle xe 11g via RPM file on Deepin OS

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I am a user of Deepin OS.
I want to install Oracle Xe 11g but when I try to install it, I get the following errors:

```
rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
error: Failed dependencies:
    glibc >= 2.3.4 is needed by oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64
    libaio >= 0.3.104 is needed by oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64
    /bin/sh is needed by oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

Deepin OS is Debian-based and similarly uses the APT package management system. As such, you won't be able to use the RPM command directly. One way to install this software would be to convert the `.rpm` package to `.deb` with [Alien](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto) - as recommended by the terminal output you've posted. You would first convert it, then go through the steps to install that new file with dpkg and apt-get. The basics of using Alien with apt packages is:

```
alien --to-deb /path/to/file.rpm
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/file.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

**Caveat:** Alien is a nifty tool but it can result in a lot of unforeseen problems when installing or running your converted software and as such it's often treated as the *last resort*. To fully commit to this method, I'd recommend following [this more thorough installation method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566734/how-to-install-oracle-11gr2-on-ubuntu-14-04), which necessitates a chkconfig script, setting some kernel parameters, and other setup steps.

---

Alternatively, have a look at [this guide](https://tuhrig.de/3-ways-of-installing-oracle-xe-11g-on-ubuntu/) which discusses using Alien but also suggests other methods for installing Oracle XE which may ultimately be less painful - including using various kind of virtualization including one method with Vagrant + Puppet, and another with Docker.

Comment: how do I fix an error when converting rpm files to deb files ?

Comment: I did not successfully convert the file using the script: sudo alien --scripts -d file.rpm and rpm -ivh file.rpm

Comment: Could you edit your original question to post the error message(s) you received when failing to convert the file?